# Use single startup script to start multiple processes and stay running

Tags: bash, process, background, startup, nohup

I want to use a single script to start multiple processes at different times. However I didn't think about the fact that it would be already running when I try to use it to start a second process. So I'm looking for something that will help me accomplish this.

Any help is very much appreciated, and if any more info is required please let me know....

ex. of what I want to do

```
./startup.sh QWER start
```

(later run it again with)

```
./startup.sh ASDF start
```

basically the script accepts 2 parameters and will just check to make sure the queue manager exists and then uses a case statement to stop/start/check status etc.

script below...

```
#!/bin/bash

#### Define vars #########################
qm=$1
QM=${qm^^}
stat=$2
proc=[I]ntroscopeAgent_$QM
MQMONITOR_BINDIR=/opt/bin/MQMonitor_$QM
#### Define New QUEUE MANAGERS ###########
declare -a QMGR=('QWER' 'ASDF' 'ZXCV' 'ASDF');
##########################################

if [[ " ${QMGR[@]} " =~ " $QM " ]]; then
case "$stat" in
  start)
        C=`ps -eo pid,args | grep "MQMonitor" | grep -c $proc`
        if [ ${C} -gt 0 ]; then
          proc_dtl=`ps -eo pid,args | grep "MQMonitor" | grep $proc`
          echo -e "\n\033[7mMQMonitor is running:\033[0m ${proc_dtl}\n\n\033[1mEither stop or restart the process\n\033[0m"
          exit 1
        fi
        echo -e "\nStarting MQMonitor MQ 9  "
        ${MQMONITOR_BINDIR}/startMQMonitor.sh &
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
          echo -e "\033[0mMQMonitor Started.. (Please see start up log in \033[1m$logfile \033[0m) \n\033[0m"
        else
          echo -e "\033[01;31mMQMonitor ${MQMONITOR_BINDIR}/startMonitor.sh didn't start cleanly\n\033[0m"
        fi
        ;;
  stop)
        echo -e "\nStopping MQMonitor ..."
        ${MQMONITOR_BINDIR}/stopMQMonitor.sh
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
          echo -e "\033[01;31mMQMonitor stopped\n\033[0m"
        else
          echo -e "\033[01;31mCouldn't stop MQMonitor\n\033[0m"
        fi
        ;;
  status)
        C=`ps -eo pid,args | grep "MQMonitor" | grep -c $proc`
        if [ ${C} -gt 0 ]; then
          PROC_ID=`ps -eo pid,args | grep "MQMonitor" | grep $proc | awk '{print $1}'`
          echo -e "\n\033[1m\033#6MQMonitor running PID: ${PROC_ID}\n\033[0m"
        else
          echo -e "\nMQMonitor not running\n"
        fi
        ;;
  restart|reload)
        C=`ps -eo pid,args | grep "MQMonitor" | grep -c $proc`
        if [ ${C} -gt 0 ]; then
          echo "MQMonitor Running..."
          echo "Stopping MQMonitor"
          ${MQMONITOR_BINDIR}/stopMQMonitor.sh
          if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "MQMonitor stopped"
          else
            echo "Couldn't stop MQMonitor"
            exit 1
          fi
          echo "Stopped"
          echo "Starting MQMonitor"
          ${MQMONITOR_BINDIR}/startMQMonitor.sh &
          if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "MQMonitor Started"
          else
            echo "MQMonitor ${MQMONITOR_BINDIR}/startMonitor.sh didn't start cleanly"
          fi
        else
          echo "MQMonitor not running"
          echo "Starting MQMonitor"
          ${MQMONITOR_BINDIR}/startMQMonitor.sh &
          if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "MQMonitor Started"
          else
            echo "MQMonitor ${MQMONITOR_BINDIR}/startMonitor.sh didn't start cleanly"
          fi
        fi
        ;;
  *)
        echo -e $"\n\n\e[41mSYNTAX ERROR:\033[0m\tPlease Use Proper Syntax: QMGR {start|stop|status|restart}\n\e[41mEx:\033[0m\t\t./mqagent QPX1 status\n\n"
exit 1
esac
else
echo -e "\n\n\e[41mPlease enter a valid Queue Manager\033[0m\n\n"
fi
```

Comment: So when I run the script a second time it seems to be using the same parameters passed to it the first time it was run. I cant figure out how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

[supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) sounds like it might help you.

Comment: Thanks for response. I think I asked the question wrong. I orignally thought the issue had something to do with fg, bg, ownership, etc. But it turns out I just had to unset the PPs for the next run.

Answer (score 0):

By unsetting the Positional Parameters I was able to pass it new ones on the next run. Added a shift command to the end to clear out the PPs.